# Why doesn't the short selling restriction apply to Moderna (MRNA) stock today?

Tags: stocks, trading, shorting-securities

Moderna's   closing price yesterday was $169.86.  Today it dropped to $147.20 (-13.3%) but the  short selling restriction rule didn't activate. Why?

[Today's SSR stocks](https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/dynamic/symdir/shorthalts/shorthalts20201209.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moderna dropped 13.3% today and it triggered the modified uptick rule today.

Your list may be dated today but it's a list of stocks that triggered yesterday.